# how to get the real url in itunes software

Tags: app-store, web-crawler, wireshark

All, I have copied a link from itunes software, 
`https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRoom?fcId=557802625&genreIdString=36&mediaTypeString=Mobile+Software+Applications`

but it will redirect to the itunes download page, so i am wondering if you have any suggestions for getting the real url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will redirect all clients that don't look like iTunes to the download page, which means you'll have to pretend to be iTunes to get the 'real' page.

Changing the User-Agent request header to match iTunes (i.e. `iTunes/9.1.1`) works for now, but there's no guarantee that it will work in the future.

If you're looking for a programmatic way to search the iTunes Store, check out the [Affiliate Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Comment: yes, i have accepted your answer, but would you mind telling me how did you find this user agent thing ?

Comment: It was a lucky guess :) The HTTP User-Agent header is the one that identifies which program the client is using, so that would be the first place for Apple to check if they are dealing with an iTunes client.